# chartjs - bar graphs size not increasing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm having an issue in setting bars width using chart.js.

This is my code:

```
<script>
            var endpoint = '/api/';

            $.ajax({
              method: "GET",
              url: endpoint,
              success: function (data) {
                drawBarGraph(data, 'myChartBar');
                console.log("drawing");
              },
              error: function (error_data) {
                console.log(error_data);
              }
            })

            
            function drawBarGraph(data, id) {
              var labels = data.labels;
              var chartLabel = data.chartLabel;
              var chartdata = data.chartdata;
              var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
              var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: labels,
                  datasets: [{
                    barThickness: 0.9,

                    label: chartLabel,
                    data: chartdata,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                  }]
                },
                options: {
                  scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                      }
                    }]
                  }
                }
              });
            } 
          </script>
```

[image: this is what I am getting]
I cannot increase the bar thickness.
I'm using [Argon Dashboard](https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-dashboard/index.html?_ga=2.2156595.2005587553.1608212320-1820097132.1605880259) with Django.

Is this an issue with theme's css?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Change this value

```
xAxes: [{
                // Change this
                barPercentage: 0.2 
            }]
```

Comment: yeah, it worked, but after refreshing the page, the bars went to old size !!

Comment: okay try these   categorySpacing: 10,
            barThickness : 100,
            barPercentage: 10

Comment: I don't know what's happening, I refresh the page and the bars are in the proper size, after refreshing again, the bars become thin...